# Create a web service "activity indicator"-like indicator compatible with all browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

My web service involves a lot of database (PHP, mySQL) activity, which leaves the user staring at a blank screen for many seconds.

The user clicks a link on an HTML page, which calls a javascript function, which in turn calls AJAX, which invokes a PHP script, and then returns.

I'd like to display an IOS-like Activity Indicator, perhaps as a "subview," if possible to show the user something is happening.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is write "Loading..." somewhere that gets overwritten or removed by the AJAX callback.

Although... "many seconds"? I run a site with hundreds of users online at any given moment with lots of server-side activity, and I almost never get a page load time over 0.2 seconds...

Comment: Thanks Kolink.  Some web services such as salesforce.com display a spinning activity indicator in a small "pop over" which disappears when data is returned.  I can't seem to find how this is done.

Comment: You mean like the one on my project? [Here it is](http://pokebattlers.net/) - click the login button without typing anything and you'll see a loading spinner. If this is the kind of thing you mean, I can help you out a bit.

Comment: That is the kind of thing. Thanks Kolink.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Well basically I create an element that has `position:fixed; left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0` and some non-transparent background. Then I create an element inside that one, which will itself hold the "Loading..." text and other stuff. The spinning circles is done with CSS and JavaScript animation and isn't really needed, so if you don't know how to do it you can just use a GIF image instead.